# How do I clear a column name in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am naming each column in a datagridview using a right-click menu with all the names the user can use. As each name is used, I have disabled the right-click menu item for each name as it is selected so that the user cannot name two columns the same. To do this, I am using a simple if statement to see if that column name exists:

```
if (MyDataGridView.Columns["ColName"] != null)
   {
      ColName.Enabled = false;
   }
```

However, if the user wants to re-name a column, I am having trouble "un-naming" the column, as the above if statement returns true for both names after I re-name the column. **Is there a way to clear a column name so that a column doesn't have multiple names associated with it?**

Comment: A column can only have 1 name. No more, no less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
MyDataGridView.Columns["ColName"].Name = string.Empty
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be more appropriate to use [DisplayName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute%28VS.90%29.aspx) attribute to specify the column name in your datagridview....